# Zoom controls not appearing after first click, for later clicks

Tags: android, android-emulator

My problem is that the zoom controls don't appear on the mapview after one click, i.e the first click after the application loads. (I am using the deprecated version.)

In my application, on a click I position a pushpin on the touched location and also generate a toast with the co-ordinates. After I click the map, the pin is re-loacated and the toast are generated (albeit a bit late, I guess because of the time for which they have to say on screen)

What is happening wrong? What gives? Are the two activities (pin and toast) stealing the touch event?

Can you suggest any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, i had to add

```
mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
```

to the function that handled all the click events. but now it doesnt pan. ill see what i can do about it.

thanks.